# How to change CSS version in Vscode?

Tags: css, node.js, typescript, version

I am using node v.12.18.4 and typscript 4.5
I am getting this error when compiling:

Failed to compile.

```
/Users/mariana/Augment Therapy/at-app/src/components/nav-item.tsx
TypeScript error in /Users/mariana/Augment Therapy/at-app/src/components/nav-item.tsx(14,30):
Argument of type '(theme: Theme) => { item: { display: string; paddingTop: number; paddingBottom: number; }; itemLeaf: { display: string; paddingTop: number; paddingBottom: number; }; button: { padding: string; justifyContent: string; textTransform: "none"; letterSpacing: number; width: string; color: string; }; ... 4 more ...; activ...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Styles<Theme, {}, "button" | "label" | "icon" | "active" | "item" | "itemLeaf" | "buttonLeaf" | "expandIcon">'.
  Type '(theme: Theme) => { item: { display: string; paddingTop: number; paddingBottom: number; }; itemLeaf: { display: string; paddingTop: number; paddingBottom: number; }; button: { padding: string; justifyContent: string; textTransform: "none"; letterSpacing: number; width: string; color: string; }; ... 4 more ...; activ...' is not assignable to type 'StyleRulesCallback<Theme, {}, "button" | "label" | "icon" | "active" | "item" | "itemLeaf" | "buttonLeaf" | "expandIcon">'.
    Call signature return types '{ item: { display: string; paddingTop: number; paddingBottom: number; }; itemLeaf: { display: string; paddingTop: number; paddingBottom: number; }; button: { padding: string; justifyContent: string; textTransform: "none"; letterSpacing: number; width: string; color: string; }; ... 4 more ...; active: { ...; }; }' and 'StyleRules<{}, "button" | "label" | "icon" | "active" | "item" | "itemLeaf" | "buttonLeaf" | "expandIcon">' are incompatible.
      The types of 'active' are incompatible between these types.
        Type '{ color: string; background: string; fontWeight: Property.FontWeight | undefined; '& $icon': { color: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties | CreateCSSProperties<{}> | PropsFunc<{}, CreateCSSProperties<{}>>'.
          Type '{ color: string; background: string; fontWeight: Property.FontWeight | undefined; '& $icon': { color: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'CreateCSSProperties<{}>'.
            Types of property 'fontWeight' are incompatible.
              Type 'FontWeight | undefined' is not assignable to type 'FontWeightProperty | PropsFunc<{}, FontWeightProperty | undefined> | undefined'.
                Type 'string & {}' is not assignable to type 'FontWeightProperty | PropsFunc<{}, FontWeightProperty | undefined> | undefined'.
                  Type 'string & {}' is not assignable to type '"lighter"'.  TS2345

    12 | import ExpandLessIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandLess';
    13 | 
  > 14 | const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
       |                              ^
    15 |   item: {
    16 |     display: 'block',
    17 |     paddingTop: 0,
```

@Diego below is pointing out the underlying issue with CSS. Does anyone know of fixes? Or how to lock my CSS type as 3.0.9? Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't look like a TypeScript version thing.  Looks like what you're passing to `makeStyles()` as the argument does not match its definition.  You don't show the makeStyles function so we can't see what it's supposed to be passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not caused by TypeScript, but by this issue: https://github.com/frenic/csstype/issues/148

Check with `npm ls csstype` which versions of `csstype` you have in your `node_modules`. I bet that some dependency resolved to csstype `3.0.10`.

Comment: Hi Diego, thanks so much for the help. When I do that it shows this: at-app@0.1.0 /Users/mariana/Augment Therapy/at-app
├─┬ @material-ui/core@4.12.3
│ ├─┬ @material-ui/styles@4.11.4
│ │ └── csstype@2.6.19 
│ ├─┬ @material-ui/system@4.12.1
│ │ └── csstype@2.6.19  deduped
│ └─┬ react-transition-group@4.4.2
│   └─┬ dom-helpers@5.2.1
│     └── csstype@3.0.10 
├─┬ @types/hookrouter@2.2.5
│ └── csstype@3.0.10 
├─┬ @types/react@16.14.21
│ └── csstype@3.0.10 
├─┬ @types/styled-components@5.1.20
│ └── csstype@3.0.10 
└─┬ jss@10.9.0
  └── csstype@3.0.10

Comment: Thanks so much again @Diego . Should I try locking the csstype to 2.6.19? Or what do you recommend in this case? I'm joining a project late and don't want to break preexisting code